# Show HTML/CSS Class after clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this Jquery-Code that copies the URL when clicked on its button (.clipboard). Now I want it **to show another HTML/CSS Class after clicking** on it.
I tried to declare it as a variable `const success = $('.success-message').html();` and then with `$('.success-message').html(success);` to run it (as you can see in the code). Unfortunately, that does not work. Is there a other way to do it? I looked it up and found the toggle method. That did not work either, or I just implemented it wrong. Appreciate any help!

Jquery:

```
var $temp = $("<input>");
var $url = $(location).attr('href');

$('.clipboard').on('click', function() {
    const originalText = $('.clipboard').html();
    const success = $('.success-message').html();
    
    // CSS function:
    const addCSS = s => document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML=s;
    
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($url).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
    $('.clipboard').html(originalText);
    $('.success-message').html(success);
    // CSS Usage: 
    addCSS(".clipboard{ font-size: 20px; padding: 4.8px 21.3px 4.8px 21.3px; }")

    // Run something in 1 seconds to revert back to the button's text
    setTimeout(function() { 
        addCSS(".clipboard{ font-size: 15px; padding: 9px 21.3px 9px 21.3px}")
        $('.clipboard').html(originalText);
    }, 1000); // 1 seconds
    
})
```

The HTML/CSS Class I want to show:

```
<div class="success-message">
    KOPIERT!
</div>

<style>
    
    .success-message{
        color: white;
        background-color: #2FAC66;
        padding: 1px 50px 1px 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
</style>
```

Comment: im confused. Did you want to change the class of your message to 'success-message, or did you want to display the css rules inside of .success-message?

Comment: What is `.clipboard`? Please provide the necessary code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to show the class "success-message" itself when clicking on that button. The button itself doesn't change. It should just show additionally the class "success-message"

Comment: .clipboard is the class-name of the button. I could provide the HTML & CSS Code from it, but its not about that part of code. When pressed on the .clipboard button, the Code I wrote here is taking action. And I want that when pressed on that, to show another HTML/CSS Class

Comment: I suppose you want to display the div with class "success-message" after the button click. 1. Add display: none to the CSS rules of .success-message 2. Grab that element and call .show() on it in the click handler function

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, that was all I needed! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete index.html as minimal working example.

Suppose, you want to show the `div.success-message` after the button has been clicked.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .success-message {
        visibility: hidden;
        color: white;
        background-color: #2fac66;
        padding: 1px 50px 1px 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Kopieren</div>
    <div class="success-message">KOPIERT!</div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam debitis
      accusamus quam nisi. Suscipit rerum nisi placeat tempore accusantium ut
      dolorum? Sit assumenda, incidunt voluptate unde optio quo enim voluptas.
    </p>
    <button class="clipboard">Kopieren!</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.when($.ready).then(function () {
        // Document is ready.
        $(".clipboard").on("click", () => {
          $(".success-message").css("visibility", "visible");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, again thank you. The '$(".success-message").show();' is what I needed! :)

Comment: Hey, its me again. I just found out, when the .success-message shows up, it pushes down the .clipboard button. Do you know how I can prevent it?

Comment: Yes, instead of display: none, use visibility: hidden to hide the element. I am not sure if you can toggle visibility with show / hide methods aswell then.

Comment: I updated the answer to use `visibility: hidden` and toggle onclick to `visibility: visible` So, the space is reserved before showing the `div.success-message`